# Resizing a selection in Adobe Acrobat X Pro

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, selection

When working with block selections, you can resize the area by dragging the handles on each of the four corners. However, I can't seem to find a way to resize the area by dragging a single side of the rectangle. If Acrobat lacks this feature, I will be surprised.

### Example:

MS Paint vs Adobe Acrobat.

[image: Paint] [image: Acrobat]

### Workaround:

I am currently using **Mouse Keys** (`Control Panel\Ease of Access...`) to move one axis at a time when dragging a corner. It works, but it is less than ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've yet to find a way to change this. However, since asking this question, I've become accustomed to using **Mouse Keys** in my workflow. I suppose Adobe would mark this as [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).